# Newline characters in external table in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a lot (think terabytes) of data that is partitioned per day (a few gigabytes per file) in a TSV format; some fields, unfortunately, have `\n` chars.

I am trying to create external table in a way that the newline chars in the data do not break the rows :( i tried the

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test
(  `column` int,  `column1` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
 ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/home/';
```

i also tried

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  'field.delim' = '\t', 'line.delim'='\n')
```

and

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)
```

In both cases i get no luck, newlines in fields cause the row to terminate :(

How can i get my tsv into hive with newlines in columns?

Comment: By `\n` chars, do you mean a  \ followed by a n ?

Comment: @Harold no, i mean newline chars

Comment: Have you tried using `regexp_replace` or regular expression to skip the `\n` character? [info](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)